# meta-analysis in R REML estimator

Tags: r, meta-analysis, reml

Does the REML estimator (default) in the R `metafor` package provides inverse-variance weighting?

Comment: Are you asking (a) if it is *possible* to do inverse-variance weighting with REML in the `metafor` package or (b) does the REML estimator do this by default?

Comment: first b, if not a + how

Comment: What code are you using to run your model? `rma(...)`?

Comment: For future questions about R code which often get closed here you might like to try the recently established mailing list for R meta-analysis queries stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis You do need to register before posting

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/metafor/metafor.pdf) for the `metafor` package lays out how it does the weighting for both fixed- and random-effects models. Random-effects models will use weights that are—in part—calculated using the inverse of the variance. However, it also includes an estimate of $\tau^2$ in the denominator (added to the variance). This is specified on page six of the documentation I linked to above. There are various types of estimation methods you can use, and they don't involve changing how weights are determined. Different types of weighting (`metafor` lets you define your own weights, if you want) can be used with different types of estimation.